how to add existing venv created by wsl in mnt folder (windows directories) to pycharm as interpreter?
I work with ubuntu via wsl on my windows 11. I have created a venv by ubuntu but in windows directories (mnt/e/bluhbluh/env). Now I can't find a way to set this venv as python interpreter in pycharm.
I've tried add interpreter on wsl, but as you can see in screenshot, it doesn't show the subdirectories and folders in windows via mnt folder.

I know that I have the option of making my venv in wsl directories, but is there any solution for this particular problem?
